# 100 height in nested div

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck on this trouble.
http://arenda2.herokuapp.com/catalog
When I use select box, jQuery add second select box ang height is change.
The scroll bord must be in one line with map.

My examples
https://jsfiddle.net/nsykfx7o/

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="filter">
        <p> Some text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
        <p> Some other text </p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.left {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

p  {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.filter {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

In .filter height must be auto, depending on content.
**.list** height must use the rest height, but not goes out of the frame 100 vh

Comment: Did not get your point. can you please explain little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you will need JavaScript. I have updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5avavtz/2/)

This is the JavaScript code (in jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list').css('height', $(window).height()-$('.filter').height());
});
```

Comment: Year, you understand correctly. I'm tried this. But this work so so.

Comment: That's it or do you need any changes?

Comment: Yeah! Thomas! Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

here's a fix for you https://jsfiddle.net/n5avavtz/1/

basically what I did is changed the height points to percent. Also changed the `overflow-y` to `auto`

Comment: Sorry, but I need scroll. I'm edit my question, may be now it's more clear